# iText encryption of pdf with certificate results in error of bouncycastle

Tags: java, pdf, encryption, certificate, itext

I get the following error when i try to encrypt a pdf with a certificate using this code:

```
public static void encryptPdf(String src, String dest, String certFile)
    throws IOException, DocumentException, CertificateException
{       
    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(src);
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        Certificate cert = Utils.getCertificate(certFile);        
        stamper.setEncryption(new Certificate[]{cert}, new int[]{PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING}, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);

    } finally {
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();             
    }
}
```

Which is basically copied from the official example: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=220

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
```

With this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine.generateWorkingKey(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.init(Unknown Source)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.crypto.AESCipher.<init>(AESCipher.java:68)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.OutputStreamEncryption.<init>(OutputStreamEncryption.java:73)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.getEncryptionStream(PdfEncryption.java:743)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfEncryption.encryptByteArray(PdfEncryption.java:756)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfString.toPdf(PdfString.java:148)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDictionary.toPdf(PdfDictionary.java:149)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfIndirectObject.writeTo(PdfIndirectObject.java:158)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.write(PdfWriter.java:420)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:398)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter$PdfBody.add(PdfWriter.java:334)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addToBody(PdfWriter.java:829)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.close(PdfStamperImp.java:316)
        at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper.close(PdfStamper.java:208)
        at de.naev.signpdf.PdfSigner.encryptPdf(PdfSigner.java:117)
        at de.naev.signpdf.Main.encrypt(Main.java:94)
        at de.naev.signpdf.Main.main(Main.java:183)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

I used: `itextpdf-5.5.3.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar, bcpkix-jdk15on-151.jar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the [Bouncycastle Security Provider](http://www.bouncycastle.org/wiki/display/JA1/Provider+Installation) and also to use the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html).

After doing that everything worked as expected.